# 404 Error for Laravel Blade view in new scotch.box

Tags: ubuntu, laravel, http-status-code-404, vagrant

So I have this whole Laravel web app already complete and working with no bugs on both my personal mac and on my company's local server. I have a work mac that I pulled down the project to and used scotch box as my vagrant server. It pulls up the home view and all the functionality works from the controllers, but will 404 when I try to navigate to another view. I know the code is right because it is working on three other machines. What could I be missing that causes the 404 on this new machine?

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /login was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu) Server at contact.dev Port 80

Comment: How does your .htaccess in the public folder look like?

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule> @lukasgeiter

Comment: The .htaccess was in the wrong location. Thanks! @lukasgeiter

Comment: Haha you're welcome (Although i didn't do much ;))

Comment: My .htaccess is in the public folder but I still have the same issue, I'm running scotchbox with vagrant and Laravel

Answer (score 2):

For future visitors, here's the solution. *(The problem was originally solved in the comments)*

Make sure your `.htaccess` file is located in the `/public/` directory of your Laravel installation.

The contents should be something similar to this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

(that's the default one that comes with a fresh installation)